# How to generate a color from a real?

Tags: colors, rgb

I have a value which is between 0.95 and 1.05
How can I generate the corresponding RGB 24-bits color (see image below) from this value ?

[image: Scale]

For example:

- 1.00 => #00FF00
- 1.05 => #FF0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value range is 1.05 - 0.95 = 0.1. So given some value x, its percentage along this range is (x - 0.95) / 0.1. This will give you some value between 0 and 1. You can then use that as the hue value in the [HSV scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) (hue/saturation/lightness) to get a color in that range.

So a value of 1.00 (what will eventually be green in your example) translates to 0.5, which could (for instance) map to a HSV code of (127, 255, 255) (you'll probably want full saturation and value, hence the 255s). Converting that to RGB is [explained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB) in the Wikipedia article and there are algorithms in many programming languages out there.